# How to add image dynamically in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I'm not getting any error, Image is not displaying, how to add an image? I think syntax I have used is wrong. please resolve this.

```js
function Person(props){
  return(
    <div class="person">
      <img src='{image_url}' />
      <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <h4>Your Age : {props.age}</h4>
      <h4>Profession : {props.profession}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

var app = (
  <div>
    <Person name="Prabhudev Vatnal" age="26" profession="Web Developer" image_url="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    <Person name="Puneeth Rajkumar" age="43" profession="Film Actor" />
    <Person name="Dwayne Johnson" age="46" profession="Wrestler" />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
.person {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick!

**Two Changes:**

- changed `<div class="person">` to `<div className="person">`
- changed `<img src='{image_url}' />` to `<img src={props.image_url} />`

```js
function Person(props){
  return(
    <div className="person">
      <img src={props.image_url} />
      <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <h4>Your Age : {props.age}</h4>
      <h4>Profession : {props.profession}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}

var app = (
  <div>
    <Person name="Prabhudev Vatnal" age="26" profession="Web Developer" image_url="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
    <Person name="Puneeth Rajkumar" age="43" profession="Film Actor" />
    <Person name="Dwayne Johnson" age="46" profession="Wrestler" />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
.person {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a syntax problem:

`function Person(props){
  return(
    <div class="person">
      <img src={props.image_url} /> // <--- {props.image_url} and not '{image_url}'
      <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <h4>Your Age : {props.age}</h4>
      <h4>Profession : {props.profession}</h4>
    </div>
  );
}`

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for above codeBase:

```
function Person(props){
  return(
    <div className='person'>
      <img src={image_url} />
      { props ? <h2>{props.name}</h2>
      <h4>Your Age : {props.age}</h4>
      <h4>Profession : {props.profession}</h4> : ''}
    </div>
  );
}
```